# Visual Studio not updating the build

Tags: c

Just started learning coding(c) and this is a simple code that I'm working on:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int A;
        int B;
        int C;
        printf("Enter A: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &A);
        printf("Enter B: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &B);
        printf("Enter C: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &C);
        if (A > B)
        {
                if (A > C)
                {
                        printf("A is largest. \n");
                }
                else
                {
                        printf("C is largest. \n");
                }
        }
        else
        {
                if (B > C)
                {
                        printf("B is largest. \n");
                }
                else
                {
                        printf("C is largest. \n");
                }
        }
return 0;
}
```

Before this, I just tested a simple program that just used 'printf' to printed out 'Testing'.

However, I had overwritten that with the above program but it is still printing out 'Testing' as the output.

P.S. if you can simplify your answer then that would be really appreciated since I'm a complete beginner at coding.

Comment: there is `}` that is not put in right place

Comment: Is it compiling without errors? If there are errors then the old version of the executable will not be overwritten by the new version.

Comment: You're missing a closing `"` on one of the `scanf_s` lines.

Comment: Sorry the syntax errors were not a problem in the original code, it happened in pasting it here. The code itself was perfect. I checked it thoroughly multiple times.

Comment: There are no errors. The solution build succeeds, but when I start the program, it just shows the previous output.

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling your code before running it? It is possible that you click the button that only runs the code (which may run automatically the last compiled code). That may be why you see output from your previous code. If you do not know what "compile" means and how it is different from running, I suggest you need to so some reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method that worked for me was to go to the solution explorer and then to my project properties and disable the 'Pre-compiled headers' in the C/C++ tab. And I also had to remove any header files or source files that were present beforehand and create a new source file with the suffix ".c" since I'm using C language.
I don't know if all this was a very basic or self explanatory solution, but since I'm VERY new to coding, I had to ask this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to store the variable using scanf(); also u can declare variables as follows: if u did not mention int before main(),than by default it returns as int type..

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
        int A,B,C;
        printf("Enter A: ");
        scanf("%d", &A);
        printf("Enter B: ");
        scanf("%d", &B);
        printf("Enter C: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &C);
        if (A > B)
        {
                if (A > C)
                {
                        printf("A is largest. \n");
                }
                else
                {
                        printf("C is largest. \n");
                }
        }
        else
        {
                if (B > C)
                {
                        printf("B is largest. \n");
                }
                else
                {
                        printf("C is largest. \n");
                }
        }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I use scanf, it shows an error saying that it is not stable and I should use scanf_s instead. I'm currently looking for a solution to that as well.

Comment: Maybe you created a new source file and did not insert it into the project?  The file being displayed by Visual Studio is not necessarily the one being compiled, and new source files are not automatically inserted into a project.